# Map: Group by common field value

Tags: apex, map

Is it possible to group by a common field value? There is no aggregate integer, just simply a shared value in a custom field.

**For example:**

```
SELECT Franchise_Account__c, Id, 
FROM Account 
WHERE Franchise_Account__c IN (:franchise_accounts)
AND RecordType.Name = 'Customers'
```

In this result each `Customer` belongs to a `Franchise_Account__c`, so I would like them grouped by that.

Essentially I would like to have a Map object to index them by, something like

```
Map<Id,List<Account>> => Map<Franchise_Account__c,List<Custom Accounts>>
```

Any thoughts on how to make this happen would be AWESOME!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We wrote a tool to do this called `GroupBy`. Unfortunately I can't share it with you, but the gist is pretty straightforward. I highly recommend adding such a tool to your library as well. The tricky part is you need a method for each type of field you can group by, and you may also want to support `Schema.SObjectField` as your field type.

An example:

```
global static Map<Date, List<sObject>> dates( String field, List<sObject> records )
{
    Map<Date, List<sObject>> returnMap = new Map<Date, List<sObject>>();
    for ( sObject record : records )
    {
        Date key = (Date)record.get( field );
        if (!returnMap.containsKey( key ))
            returnMap.put( key, new List<sObject> ());
        returnMap.get( key ).add( record );
    }
    return returnMap;
}
```

After templating that out for all the types you want to support, your usage would look like:

```
Map<Id,List<Account>> franchiseToAccounts = GroupBy.ids('Franchise_Account__c', [
    SELECT Franchise_Account__c
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Franchise_Account__c IN (:franchise_accounts)
    AND RecordType.Name = 'Customers'
]);
```